# PR doesn't reflect changes to master in "Files changed"

Tags: git, github, deployment, pull-request

I had a PR open. I made another PR to separate some of the logic. that PR got pushed to master. However, in the original PR, it doesn't recognize the changes I pushed to master, ie it still shows the changes as if they are new.

Can I fix this without pulling from master? If it's already in master,shouldn't it propagate in File Changes?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's nothing special about `master` (or any branch, for that matter) that makes it automatically propagate to any other branch. In order for the changes in `master` to be reflected in your other branch, you have to either rebase it to master (`git rebase master`), or merge master into it (`git merge master`).

Further, the branch that exists on your local machine is actually different from the branch that exists on GitHub, even though they're likely named the same thing. If you merge master into your local branch, you'll then have to push it to get it to show up in the PR (and, indeed, for any of your collaborators to see the change reflected in your branch at all). And before merging master at all, you'll need to pull GitHub's master into your master so that the changes are reflected on your machine (unless they were made on your machine in the first place). The following commands should accomplish it start-to-finish:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull
$ git checkout my-branch
$ git merge master
$ git push
```

Comment: I did merge master into it; my question is that my PR still shows as if I haven't, as if all the changes are new (even the ones that were pushed in)

Comment: Gotcha, I've edited the answer with more info.